# Start new containers from inside docker

Tags: docker

This is not about docker-in-docker, the new containers should be run on the host.

My application is split into multiple containers. The main application, which also contains a web UI for management purposes, is in container A. A collection of scripts to actually execute the management tasks is mounted into container A as a volume. Container A is based off image A, a custom crafted image for the main application.

Also available is image B for plugins. But when no plugins are active, no containers B_x should be started. All plugins share the same image, but for various reasons, each plugin has to run in its own container.

The user should now be able to add and remove plugins. That means:

- Creating new configuration data for the plugin
- Writing the configuration data to a location on the host, which will only be accessible to container A and a plugin container B_n
- Starting a new container B_n based off image B with the respective volumes mounted
- And, if the plugin should be delted, undoing these steps.

This all should happen through the UI in container A.

Is this even possible? And how would I approach it?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. First you need to share your docker socket with the container that will start new containers. With docker cli that could be as simple as this:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock image:tag
```

Having done that you now have a choice. As this socket exposes an HTTP REST API you could address that directly with HTTP calls or via a programming language library (they exist for most popular languages). Or, you could install the docker cli client in your image and as that interacts with `/var/run/docker.sock`, which is mounted to the equivalent path on the host, this will run containers (or build images if you wanted to) on the host.

The only complexity left will be mounting volumes. There is no easy solution to this beyond not mounting the host volume at all and using docker volumes instead. Using docker volumes is almost always preferable to mounting the host filesystem anyway, so this shouldn't be too much trouble for you.

One thing to note (thanks to @BMitch's comment for the reminder), is that you can have some security issues doing this as it is likely that you will effectively be giving your containers root access to the host system because docker runs as root. So, be careful. However, this risk can be mitigated by using trusted images and base-images and always keeping them patched.

Comment: Just realize that mounting the docker socket inside the container gives processes inside the container full root level access to the host. So only do this with commands you'd trust to run outside of a container as root.

Comment: That's a good point -- I'll add a note to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Let's assume I started A with `docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container imgA`. Can I use this volume when running (now inside A) `docker run -v ???:/path/in/B`, and how?

Comment: No, you can't rebind it